# VBA: How to enter a value according to another value in the same row but different column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Can you please help me figure out what is the way to enter a value to a cell in one column according to a value in a different column but the same row?

let's say I don't know where is the column but I do know what is the Header name and I know how to find it and declare it as a range.

- Input:

| Fruit | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Banana |  |
| Kiwi |  |
| Watermelon |  |

Desired Output:

| Fruit | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Yellow |
| Kiwi | Green |
| Watermelon | Red |

So far I tried:

```
For i = 2 To numOfDataRows
    If ((RngB.Cells(i, Fruit_address).Value = "Banana") Or (RngB.Cells(i, 
        Fruit_address).Value = "Lemon")) Then
        Rng12.Cells(i, Color_address).Value = "Yellow"
    End If
Next i
```

**RngB is my Range for the fruits column. not necessarily column B.
Rng12 is my Range for the Colors column. not necessarily column G.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `Fruit_address`? And `Color_address`? The second argument of `Cells` should be the column index or letter.

Comment: Yes, as you said the second argument of Cells is the column index. I checked ant it is the correct value. But still not working this way? Do you think it should work? Maybe some other way using a function?

Comment: Sure, but from the code you included that's not clear. Please create a [reprex]. Also it's not clear what the problem is (error code, wrong values,...).

Comment: Ok I'll keep it in mind for next time. Maybe you know any other way i can make it happen? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is or what you're exactly trying to do, unfortunately.